# How to display the multiselect dropdown value in table td in angular 8

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have a form where I have dropdowns and multi select dropdowns and on submitting the form values we are displaying the values in the table.

as for multi select, user can select multiple values so the data is saving as an array as shown below-

```
[
{id: "xyz", name: "Developer Back"},
{id: "xyz", name: "Developer front"}
]
```

The role form structure-

html -

```
<div class="p-field form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="role" class="col-form-label">Role</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <p-multiSelect
        [options]="resourceRoles | dropdownToValuePipe"
        placeholder="Select"
        name="roles"
        id="roles"
        ngModel
        required
        appendTo="body"
      >
      </p-multiSelect>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I show this multiple values in roles columns of table?

```
td{{ roles }} </td>
```

Kindly help giving some solutions for the above issues.

Comment: you should use *ngFor with some styling inside the cell you want to display the values in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
<td>
  <span *ngFor="let role of roles">{{role.name}}</span>
</td>
```

some styling will probably be needed to make it look decent

Comment: <span *ngFor ="let role of resource.roles"> {{ role }}</span>
I am getting something like this in the table cell [object Object] [object Object]. Do you know how can I convert this object into text @Moshezauros

Comment: see the example I pasted, role is an object, if you want to display a property from it (like name), use `{{role.name}}` instead of `{{role}}`

Comment: <td>
            <span *ngFor ="let role of resource.roles">
              {{ role.name }}
          </span>
          </td> I am getting the output now. But how can I add styling I need to put at least comma to separate the data

Comment: use css, you can add `<span *ngFor="let role of roles" style="margin-right: 10px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid black;">{{role.name}}</span>`